# Transforming MS Office XML

Tags: xslt, ms-office, xls

Thanks to Will I've made some progress with generating my own XSLT, however this XML has me completely stuck and resembles nothing I've worked with. Since it uses the MS Office stylesheet it opens up in Excel but sadly I'm working on an automated process.

Any clues on how I can achieve this will be welcome.

Transform raw XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
<ss:Styles/>
<ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Information">
<ss:Table>
<ss:Row>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Name</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Age</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Unit</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
<ss:Row>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Sally</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">29</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Greenford</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
<ss:Row>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Dave</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">45</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell>
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Paddington</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
</ss:Table>
</ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

Into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Report Title="Location">
<Record>
<Name>Sally</Name>
<Age>29</Age>
<Unit>Greenford</Unit>
</Record>
<Record>
<Name>Dave</Name>
<Age>45</Age>
<Unit>Paddington</Unit>
</Record>
</Report>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet will give you the desired output XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" exclude-result-prefixes="ss">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Match the table, output the root node and select the rows
       excluding the row that contains the header. -->
  <xsl:template match="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <Report Title="Location">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ss:Row[not(position()=1)]"/>
    </Report>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Now we're at a row. Match the data in each cell. -->
  <xsl:template match="ss:Row">
    <Record>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>
    </Record>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Output an element for each piece of data. -->
  <xsl:template match="ss:Data">
    <!-- Find which column we are at. -->
    <xsl:variable name="column" select="count(../preceding-sibling::ss:Cell) + 1"/>
    <!-- The name of the element comes from the corresponding column 
     in the header (the first row). -->
    <xsl:element name="{//ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row[1]/ss:Cell[$column]/ss:Data}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Ben - many thanks. When I attempt to apply the transformation I get Expected QName:name="{//ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row[1]/ss:Cell[$column]/ss:Data}"

Comment: This XSL works for me with your example XML. You can see it in action [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/51CV09). Are you applying it to different input XML?

Comment: Can't deny you that! Must be the app I'm presenting the XSLT to. Ben thanks. And thanks for introducing me to xmlplayground. That is going to prove very useful :)